# Why would you ever need to return a value for a function in Python?

Tags: python, function

This is something I've yet to understand. I'm taking online coursework for Python and the code I wrote below works for determining if a number is even, obviously. Below that is the example I was shown in a question that does the same thing, except it uses 'return' and isn't as easily reusable.

```
# MY CODE
def isEven(num):
if num % 2 == 0:
    print(num, "is even.")
else:
    print(num, "is not even")

# INSTRUCTOR EXAMPLE
def isEven(num):
    return num % 2 == 0

if isEven(3):
    print("3 is even")
else:
    print("3 is not even")
```

This is a simple example, but I can't imagine a time where I would ever need to return a value from a function I define. Why would I ever need to use return or return a value from a function?

Comment: Okay, so you know how you can do things like `my_int = int('3')`? How do you think `int` is communicating the value back so you can assign it?

Comment: *The version that returns a value* is more reusable. The one that prints can only be used for one thing: printing what it found in a specific format. The `return` one can be used any time you need to check whether a number is even. (Of course, checking if a number is even is pretty short itself, but think about it with a more complicated function, like checking if a number is prime.)

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong. Don't make us guess what your code should actually look like; [edit] to fix the formatting. (On the desktop version of this site, paste your code, select it, and type ctrl-K.)

Comment: *"isn't as easily reusable"* -> is substantially *more* reusable, because it makes fewer assumptions about what the output should be.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? Can anyone who downvoted explain the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You return a value so that the function can be used in different ways. For instance, you can use it to filter a list.

```
l = [1, 2, 10, 5, 7]
evens = list(filter(isEven, l))
print(events)
```

or you can print different messages:

```
if isEven(len(l)):
    print("The length of l is even")
```

This makes the function *more* reusable, not less. If all the function does is print a message, it can't be used for anything more general.

Comment: I still don't get it. You could just modify the code in the function to be what you need it to be, what I showed was just an example of seeing if a number is even.

Comment: The point is that you don't want to write a new `isEven` function for each different thing you want to do with even numbers.

Comment: Okay, that still doesn't make any sense to me. Doesn't matter, though. I just now gave up on coding. Thanks for the response anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should return values when you want to use the result of the function somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Defining and naming functions (and passing values into and out of them) is a way of organising code, which becomes necessary once you're beyond a couple of dozen lines.

Typical real-life projects will often have many thousands of lines, occasionally millions, so some level of organisation is needed to keep track of what's happening where.